# Feature Request: Last activity in suggested edits

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, review

I would like to make a feature request for the suggest edits review page.

The review page should show that last date of activity of the entire thread, not just the post which is being edited.

The rationale is that sometimes an old thread would be bumped for one reason or another (a new answer, a revision, someone editing it otherwise), in which case continuing improvements of posts on the same thread is a reasonable course of action. When I see a bumped thread I am more likely to correct very minor mistakes, which I would ignore otherwise.

I am certain that I am not the only one. I think this information is important, and edits should not be approved solely on the fact that they add something. If the correction is minor, and the post is on the front page -- I would definitely approve it. If the correct is minor and the post is buried deep into the archives of the site, I am less likely to approve (and sometimes even reject) the edit. I believe that I am not the only one holding such opinion.